# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in... while connecting PHP 5.4.22 and MySQL 5.5 with Apache 2.4.7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect PHP 5.4.22 and MySQL 5.5 with Apache 2.4.7 as the web server. All three of these individually are working fine. However, when I try to connect PHP with MySQL I get the error:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in..."

#### db_connect.php code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mylab_dev");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$conn->close();
```

#### httpd.conf configuration:

```
ServerRoot "c:/Apache24"

#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll" (Verified the existence of the physical file)

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
PHPIniDir c:/php
```

Modified php.ini-development file to php.ini

```
; extension_dir = "./"

; On windows:

extension_dir = "ext"

extension=php_mysql.dll  --> Uncommented

extension=php_mysqli.dll --> Uncommented
```

Set the date timezone accordingly

One thing I noticed but not sure if this is the reason, in the `phpinfo()` page I see the MySQL information, but I don't see anything which says `mysqli()`. Should I?

Comment: Why do you think "the reason is different"?

Comment: Try set `extension_dir` to full path (eg `C:\Path\To\PHP\ext`) restart your Apache server and run code again.

Comment: Thanks Barell, it worked! :) This is the height of embarrassment! I have been breaking my head over this few days but it never came to head that this is the reason and so simple! Thanks a ton!

Comment: barell you should make your comment an answer. id vote for it. it totally fixed my problem too :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, make sure you are editing the correct `php.ini` by checking from the `phpinfo()`.

I wrote these instructions mainly for Windows users:

Edit your `php.ini`.

Check whether variable `extension-dir` is set properly. If not, specify the correct path as per your OS.

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\php\ext"
```

Un-comment these lines by removing the `;` (semi-colon):

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, and I fixed it with these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

This connection for PHP 5.5/MySQL seems to work for me.

```
$host = "localhost";
$db = "mydatabse";    // Database name
$user = "my_username"; // User
$pass = "my_passxx"; // Password

// My PHP 5.5 method of connecting to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the path for php.ini by checking from the phpinfo(). Copy the php.ini file to the address shown in path.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove and replace the default PHP 5.5.9 packages that come with Ubuntu 14.04 with the versions from the ppa.

```
sudo aptitude install pkg-php-tools php5.6 php5.6-cgi php5.6-cli php5.6-dbg php5.6-common php5.6-curl php5.6-gd php5.6-imap php5.6-intl php5.6-mysql php5.6-pspell php5.6-sqlite3 php5.6-tidy php5.6-opcache php5.6-json php5.6-bz2 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-readline php5.6-xmlrpc php5.6-enchant php5.6-xsl php-all-dev php7.0 php7.0-cgi php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-dbg php7.0-curl php7.0-enchant php7.0-gd php7.0-imap php7.0-intl php7.0-ldap php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-readline php7.0-pspell php7.0-tidy php7.0-xmlrpc php7.0-xsl php7.0-json php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-bz2 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

https://www.23systems.net/2016/01/installing-php-5-6-x-7-0-x-ubuntu-14-04-virtualmin-5-0gpl-using-ppa/