# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() while module is Loaded

Tags: php, mysqli, fatal-error

I have read all the answers concerning the PHP error, therefore, I have already checked:

1. php.ini extension calling the library
2. checking the actual file that is being loaded by apache
3. Dinamicaly checking loaded modules from php ($list = get_loaded_extensions(); ) which displays

   `[21] => mysql
   [22] => mysqli
   [28] => pdo_mysql
   [29] => pdo_sqlite`
4. I have restarted Apache
5. the  extension path is correctly written
6. the file php_mysqli.dll exists there

This fatal error ocurred after trying to install SugarCRM community edition. Installer program showed a lot of Strict errors so I edited php.ini file to set error_reporting to `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT` as answer in some StackOverflow questions.

Error occurs on `\include\database\MysqliManager.php on line`

```
$this->database = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$configOptions['db_user_name'],$configOptions['db_password'],isset($configOptions['db_name'])?$configOptions['db_name']:'',$dbport);
```

Running wamp on Windows 7 with PHP 5.4.12. Any hints appreciated

Comment: So, what's the question; ah yes, in the question's "title". Will you lookah dat. Make sure you're not using any instance of `mysql_`. I've installed Wamp last week with no problems, same OS. I did get the deprecated warning because of the default SQL script, but I quickly fixed that. Plus, make sure you restart "all services". Show full code if you have any to share.

Comment: As that function is only an alias, try to use the aliased implementation instead and show how you did that and update whether or not it worked and what the result was.

Comment: Please see this thread there maybe some answers you may find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116491/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect-in-while-connecting/28346790#28346790

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer:

If you don't mind using a different tool you can save time and ditch `wamp`

[I have seen this happen many times.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26208509/1880431)

Use [**xampp**](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) instead, it has the same features but less issues like this one you are encountering.