# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect(). I've tried everything, and I'm out of ideas

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I'm trying to connect my `MySQL` database to my website that I'm working on, which is written in `PHP`, but it always says

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\socialtest\inc\connect.inc.php on line 7

I'm using `PHP 5.6.9`, `MySQL5.6`, and `Apache2.2`.

I figured out that the problem is my `connect.inc.php` file which has the code where I connect to the database. Here's the code in that file:

```
 <?php
    DEFINE ('DB_USER','admin');
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD','aldotheapache12');
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST','localhost');
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME','socialtest');

    $dbc =        mysqli_connect(DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_HOST,DB_NAME);
    OR die('Captian, we have failed' .
    mysqli_connect_error());
    ?>
```

I've uncommented the `mysqli` extensions in the `php.ini` file, restarted my apache servers, checked my code hundreds of times over for errors and nothing has worked. I've tried tons of others things too that I've forgotten, and I'm out of ideas now. If anyone has any new suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: look at the php info: `<?php phpinfo(); die();?>` to see if it's enabled

Comment: I don't see the mysqli extension. I only see a part that says mysqlnd when I run phpinfo();

Comment: then mysqli isn't enabled on your server...

Comment: Locate the correct php.ini and in there either un-comment the line `extension=php_mysqli.dll` or add it. (also check whether the `ext` directory contains this .dll and `extension_dir` points to this directory). Then re-start the httpd.

Comment: @VolkerK I already tried uncommenting the     extension=php_mysqli.dll
And yes, the ext directory does contain it

Comment: @MarcB how do I enable it? The PHP manual says on PHP versions 5.3+ it's already enabled. So seeing as I'm using PHP 5.6.9 it should already be enabled.....

Comment: @NotInternetExplorer are you sure you're editing the correct `php.ini` file. The output of `phpinfo()` will tell you which configuration file(s) it's using.

Comment: @Phil it says that there's no loaded configuration file. How do I direct it to php.ini?

Comment: Please check this link to see whether it answers your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116491/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect-in-while-connecting/28346790#28346790